# Approximation of a function by a Taylor polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need help with this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The taski is:

Approach the function $f(x)=\sin^2 (x)$ by a Taylor polynomial of the fourth degree near the point $x_0=0$.

I did this:

$$f(x)=\sin^2 (x)\\f(0)=0\\f′(0)=0\\f′′(0)=2\\f′′′(0)=0\\f^{IV}(0)=-8\\f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f′(0)}{1!}(x-0)+\frac{f′′(0)}{2!}(x-0)^2 + \frac{f′′′(0)}{3!}(x-0)^3+\frac{f^{(IV)}(0)}{4!}(x-0)^4+o\left(x^4\right)\\f(x)=x^2 -\frac{x^4 }{3}+o(x^4)$$

Is that right ?

Comment: Apparently yes: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+sin%28x%29%5E2+at+x%3D0

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: It is right, but much simpler with just some trigonometry:
$$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}2,$$
and the standard Taylor-Young's formula for the cosine yields instantly
$$\cos 2x=1-2x^2+\frac{2x^4}3+o\bigl(x^4\bigr).$$